# How can I vertically center flexbox with two rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a flexbox grid with two columns and I can't figure out how to vertically center it. I've tried to nest the whole thing within a flexbox, but it puts all of the divs on the same line instead of keeping the grid-like layout.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for the ambiguity. I would like for the two columns to be centered vertically on the page so they are halfway down the page instead of at the top, like they are now. I would still like them to be in two columns and one be on the left side of the page and the other on the right.

Relevant HTML:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Header1</div>
  <div class="col">Header2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
  <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want a grid-like layout, why not use [CSS Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I suppose I could, but the flexbox is working fine at the moment. I'm only using these two columns and rows so I don't need an extensive grid. Is what I want easier to achieve with CSS grids?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. When I run your code, I see exactly what I would expect: A row with Header1 and Header2 in two cells of 50% width, followed by a row with two buttons immediately below Header1 and Header2. Looks pretty grid-like to me.

Comment: _ *how to vertically center it*  Can you clarify ? How is it supposed to look alike ? Looks like you turn 2 tr/td into divs . Should it center vertically in the middle of the screen or the screen split in two rows of 50% of height each , else ?.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus My apologies for the ambiguity. The two columns should be side by side and share 50% of the screen each. So Header1 should be directly above the first button, but those two together should be on the left half of the screen. Header2 should go with the second button and be on the right side of the screen. I would like both columns to be centered on the screen as well, so they're halfway down the page instead of right at the top.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I updated my post with an edit to clarify what I'm looking for. What you see is what I want, but I want that grid-like structure to be pushed further down the page so it's centered instead of at the top.

Comment: oki, since your code looked a lot alike <tr><td><td> , here is an example based on the table display : https://jsfiddle.net/8s06do2f/1/ or with a wrapper to avoid bugs : https://jsfiddle.net/8s06do2f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly...

To center your contents vertically, you need a wrapper element that has the full height of the window. So in my example below there's a "wrapper" element with 100% height which has `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: center` in order to center it's contents vertically.

Also, for the `height: 100%` to be effective, you also need to apply that to all parent elements, in this case `html` and `body`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Header1</div>
    <div class="col">Header2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
    <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If (theoretically) what you posted is already the whole contents of that page, you can also omit using the wrapper div at all and apply its settings to the `body` element.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for. This centers the two columns in the middle of the page, but they're right next to each other. It seems like the flex-basis isn't working. Is it possible to keep them separated like in my original code but have them centered in the middle of the page like in your code above?

Comment: In the result in the snippet window here they are *not*  next to each other, and I simply took the code you posted and added the wrapper, so there must be something else in your code which you *didn't*  post that causes a difference between the snippet here and your result.

Comment: You *can*  add `width: 50%` to the `.row` rule.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. I realized I had a conflict in class names and that was causing the unexpected behavior. Once I cleared that up, it worked right away. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.grid .grid-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="col">Header1</div>
      <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="col">Header2</div>      
      <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code does and why.

Comment: [Edit] your answer to include the explanation.

Comment: I tried this but this creates one column with 4 rows, all centered horizontally but not vertically. I made an edit on my original post to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.col {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Header1</div>
    <div class="col">Header2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
    <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code does and why.

Comment: To avoid two columns, The width of the row class should be 100%. And div of col class should be text-align: center; to make element's position as center.

Comment: [Edit] your answer to include the explanation.

Comment: I tried this but this creates one column with 4 rows, all centered horizontally but not vertically. I made an edit on my original post to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to make rows `100%` wide and instruct the container to break if children are wider than its width by adding `flex-wrap` property. Since its child is as much wide as the parent this will break for every new child. Lastly, you can fully center everything by adding the `justify-content` property to `cols`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">Header1</div>
      <div class="col">Header2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
      <div class="col"><button>Click here</button></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

But as @Heretic Monkey said it might be better to use `grid`

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code does and why.

Comment: @HereticMonkey for sure, I thought it was self-explanatory. My mistake..

Comment: I tried this but it isn't producing my desired results. It produces two rows and two columns, but they are at the top of the screen. I'm hoping to get them in the middle of the screen, so they are halfway down the page instead of at the top.